# Will the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(t)$ converge in $C([0,1])$ where $f_n(t)=(-1)^n\frac{t^n}{n}$. Is the convergence absolute?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

> Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(t)$ converge in $C([0,1])$ where $f_n(t)=(-1)^n\frac{t^n}{n}$. Is the convergence absolute?

By the alternating series test since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{t^n}{n} = 0$ as $t \in [0,1]$ and since $\frac{t^n}{n}$ is a decreasing sequence we can conclude that $\sum_{n =1}^\infty f_n(t) <\infty$.

The convergence is not absolute since $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|f_n(t)\|_\infty = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|(-1)^n \frac{t^n}{n}\|_\infty = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|(-1)^n\|_\infty \|\frac{t^n}{n}\|_\infty = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$$
and the harmonic series diverges.

I'm having doubts about the equality $$\|(-1)^n\|_\infty \|\frac{t^n}{n}\|_\infty = \frac{1}{n}$$

I think that $\|(-1)^n\|_\infty = \sup_{n \in \Bbb N} |(-1)^n| = 1$ and that $\|\frac{t^n}{n}\|_\infty = \sup_{n \in \Bbb N} |\frac{t^n}{n}| = \frac{1}{n}$ because $t^n$ has a maximum value at $1$. Are these observations correct?

Comment: I think the supremum should be taken for $t\in[0, 1]$, not for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Yes, but there are no $t$'s in $\|(-1)^n\|_\infty$ for example? @Riemann

Comment: @Epilogue The $\|\cdot\|_\infty$-norm considers $(-1)^n$ as a function in $t$. Here, a constant function. The supremum must not be taken in $n$  (though the answer is of course the same in this case)

Comment: @FShrike It's should be still $1$?

Comment: @Epilogue Yes it is $1$, the answer is the same, as I said. But consider $t\mapsto n$. $\|n\|_{\infty}=n$... but $\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}|n|=\infty$. The "$n$" is irrelevant in that you are not supposed to consider it as part of a sequence

Comment: For all $0\leq t<1$ you have absolute convergence, for $t=1$ you don't. You still have uniform convergence in $[0,1]$ (Abel's criteria).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is false that $\|f\cdot g\|_\infty=\|f\|_\infty\|g\|_\infty$. Take, for instance, $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=1-x$. Then $\|f\|_\infty=\|g\|_\infty=1$, but $\|f\cdot g\|_\infty=\frac14$.

However, it is true that $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\|f_n\|_\infty=\frac1n$. Therefore, yes, your series is not absolutely convergent.

However, your proof of convergence is flawed. All you did was to prove that, for *each* $t\in[0,1]$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{t^n}n$ converges. This is weaker than proving that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges in $C([0,1])$. You can prove that it converges by proving that it is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Actually, what I proved was that the sequence converges *uniformly*. I don't recall having written that post. Thank you for calling my attention to it.

Comment: Sure you did, this bad cold is scrambling my thoughts